# Tikz - cannot figure out why my lines won't connect

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, graphs

I cannot figure out why my code doesn't compile into the attached image, not sure if I am missing something in how Tikz works or there's another issue:

**Code**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (1) {$1$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (2) [right of=1] {$2$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (3) [below of=1] {$3$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (4) [right of=3] {$4$};
        \path[]
        (4) edge [loop below] node (4)
        (1) [-] edge node[right] (2)
        (1) [-] edge node[below] (3)
        (2) [-] edge node[above] (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

**What it should look like**

[image: Forgive the sloppiness]

**What it does look like**

[image: Lines do not connect as advertised]

Comment: Hi, welcome. The first thing to note is perhaps that your code throws an error, so you cannot really expect the output to be correct.

Comment: It didn't throw an error in my editor but I tossed it in a linter and sure enough, I need labels for lines even if they are empty. This solves it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had unnecessary nodes in the path. (celi solved the problem in [their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474590/121799) by adding `{}`, which makes the code compile but adds nodes that seem not to be used.)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (1) {$1$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (2) [right of=1] {$2$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (3) [below of=1] {$3$};
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (4) [right of=3] {$4$};
        \path[]
        (4) edge [loop below] (4)
        (1) [-] edge  (2)
        (1) [-] edge  (3)
        (2) [-] edge  (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @deversEatsALot used nodes with placement, so i figured he wanted a label there eventually, but you are right, your solution is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (1) {$1$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (2) [right of=1] {$2$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (3) [below of=1] {$3$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (4) [right of=3] {$4$};
\path (1) edge [] node [left] {} (2)
(1) edge [] node [below] {} (3)
(2) edge [] node [above] {} (3)
(4) edge [loop above] node[] {} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]